# Flask-SQLAlchemy - how to a autoload a table from a Bind (second database)

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use `autoload` for a table in `Flask-SQLAlchemy` when using a secondary database?

I've tried to set up `bind_key` in `config.py` so that I can access two separate databases, but I can't get it to `autoload` the table from the secondary database `db2`

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class TAB1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'TABLE1'
    __bind_key__ = 'db1'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }
    
class TAB2(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    __tablename__ = 'TABLE2'

    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }
```

`config.py`

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:example@database1-db:9001/database1"
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'db2': "postgres://postgres:example@database2-db:9002/database2",
    'db1': SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
}
```

I get an error:

```sh
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: `TABLE2`
```

I suspect that I need to change the `autoload_with` to refer to the `bind_key` in some way, but can't work out how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out, it's:

```
'autoload_with': db.get_engine(bind="db2")
```

Answer (score -1):

'autoload_with' :db.get_engine(bind_key='your_bind_key')

Comment: The difference between your solution and the upvoted accepted one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62837530/7733418) seems to only be that you are using a placeholder and a different quotation. Please explain what relevance that difference has so that you consider your post a relevant additional insight. If this is the same please instead upvote the existing one and delete this.